# Looping through text boxes, using id as a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm trying to populate an array with some values in text boxes. I thought I could do it by incrementing though ids, but it isn't working.

Here it is:

```js
var sections = 0;
var mod = [];
var identifier = 0;

function addSection(){

 sections++;

 document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
 document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
 document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'> <br>";
}

function removeSection(){
 if (sections > 0){
  sections--;
  identifier -= 3;
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "";

  for(i=0; i<sections; i++){
   document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
   document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
   document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'> <br>";
  }

 }
}

function calculate(){
 populateArray();
}

function populateArray(){

 var i,j;
 
 for(i=0;i<sections * 3;i++){
  var pop = i.toString();
  mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(pop).innerHTML.value);
  i++;

  pop = i.toString();
  mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(pop).innerHTML.value);
  i++

  pop = i.toString();
  mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(pop).innerHTML.value);
 }
 document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = mod.toString();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>To Pass v1.0</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>TO PASS</h1>

<button onclick="addSection()">Add Section</button>
<button onclick="removeSection()">Remove Section</button>
<div id='input'></div>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<div id='output'></div>
<div id='debug'></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Is it possible doing it my method, or will it inevitably not work for whatever reason? Doing some searches it seems jquery might be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to get started with that.

Comment: If you want to learn jquery http://learn.jquery.com/ is your first port of call. You can do this in pure Js though. JQuery (once you've learned it) may make it easier though.

Comment: Rather than having the var 'sections' be a counter of elements, you could just have it be an array of the elements themselves and loop through it that way.

Comment: Not getting, what you trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery certainly simplifies things, but it can't do anything that JavaScript can't do, and many amazing websites were built long before jQuery came into existence.

---

In `populateArray()`, remove `innerHTML` here:

```
mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(pop).innerHTML.value);
```

Should be:

```
mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(pop).value);
```

You can simplify the function like this:

```
function populateArray() {
  var i;

  for(i = 0 ; i < sections * 3 ; i++) {
    mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(i).value);
  }
  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = mod.toString();
}
```

---

In `addSection()`, this wipes out the values of existing `input` elements:

```
document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
```

Instead, you should create new `input` elements and append them.

Here's a rewrite of the function:

```
var input= document.getElementById('input');

function addSection(){
  var inp, i;

  sections++;

  for(var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
    inp= document.createElement('input');
    inp.type= 'text';
    inp.id= identifier++;
    input.appendChild(inp);
  }
  input.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
} //addSection
```

---

In `removeSection()`, values of all `input` elements are wiped out.

Instead of rewriting that function, I've done a complete rewrite or your program, without any global variables and without assigning IDs to the `input` elements.

If you have any questions, I'll update my answer with explanations.

**Snippet**

```js
function addSection() {
  var input= document.getElementById('input'),
      sect= document.querySelector('section');
  
  input.appendChild(sect.cloneNode(true));
}

function removeSection() {
  var input= document.getElementById('input'),
      sects= document.querySelectorAll('section');
  
  if(sects.length > 1) {
    input.removeChild(sects[sects.length-1]);
  }
}

function calculate() {
  var inp= document.querySelectorAll('section input'),
      debug= document.getElementById('debug'),
      mod= [],
      i,
      val;

  for(i = 3 ; i < inp.length ; i++) {
    val= parseInt(inp[i].value);
    mod.push(val || 0);
  }
  debug.innerHTML = mod.toString();
}
```

```css
section:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addSection()">Add Section</button>
<button onclick="removeSection()">Remove Section</button>

<div id='input'>
  <section>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </section>
</div>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<div id='output'></div>
<div id='debug'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This version of your script stores the actual elements in an array of sections. That way you can loop through them as you would an array, and alter the contents that way.

Here's a pen of the code: [looping through added elements](http://codepen.io/dugweb/pen/VLKeab)

```
var sections = [];
var output = document.getElementById('input');

function addSection(){

    var section = document.createElement('div');

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = 'text';

    section.appendChild(el);
    }

  sections.push(section);
  output.appendChild(section);
}

function removeSection(){
    if (sections.length > 0){
        output.removeChild(sections.pop())
    }
}

function calculate(){
    populateArray();
}

function populateArray(){

    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {

      for (var j = 0; j < sections[i].children.length; j++ ) {
       sections[i].children[j].value = (i+1) * (j+2); 
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the NaN, this is because you select an input field and then first try to read its innerHtml before reading its value. Read values of inputs directly.

```js
var sections = 0;
var mod = [];
var identifier = 0;

function addSection(){

 sections++;

 document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
 document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
 document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'> <br>";
}

function removeSection(){
 if (sections > 0){
  sections--;
  identifier -= 3;
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "";

  for(i=0; i<sections; i++){
   document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
   document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'>";
   document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='" + identifier++ + "'> <br>";
  }

 }
}

function calculate(){
 populateArray();
}

function populateArray(){

 var i,j;
 
 for(i=0;i<sections * 3;i++){
  var pop = i.toString();
  mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(pop).value);
  i++;

  pop = i.toString();
  mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(pop).value);
  i++

  pop = i.toString();
  mod[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(pop).value);
 }
 document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = mod.toString();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>To Pass v1.0</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>TO PASS</h1>

<button onclick="addSection()">Add Section</button>
<button onclick="removeSection()">Remove Section</button>
<div id='input'></div>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<div id='output'></div>
<div id='debug'></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```